# What is the difference between Ansible Inventory Plugins and inventory scripts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-tower

Most of the tutorials that I found online discuss using scripts for Dynamic inventories.
Ansible recommends using plugins for Dynamic inventories, but even in Ansible Tower, there is the option to create Inventory Scripts but nothing on plugins.

Answer (score 2):

On the developing page in Ansible documentation it [describes the difference pretty well.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html)

> In previous versions you had to create a script or program that can
>   output JSON in the correct format when invoked with the proper
>   arguments. You can still use and write inventory scripts, as we
>   ensured backwards compatibility via the script inventory plugin and
>   there is no restriction on the programming language used. If you
>   choose to write a script, however, you will need to implement some
>   features yourself. i.e caching, configuration management, dynamic
>   variable and group composition, etc. While with inventory plugins you
>   can leverage the Ansible codebase to add these common features.

So while the inventory plugin might sound appealing as it provides many additional features of inventory automatically, there are some limitations:

> Like most plugin types (except modules) they must be developed in
>   Python, since they execute on the controller they should match the
>   same requirements Control node requirements.

The issue is that for some systems it might be very hard to develop a plugin with python and all ansible requirements. Some might even provide a working script in some other language that simply can be adjusted for ansible, so it might be easier for the user to simply use a script they are familiar with.